# Run a java program after final web page

Tags: java, multithreading, jsf

I hava an app on JSF where I upload a file. Very basic. The question is, is there a way to launch (or keep executing) another java program when I reach the last page of my app? That is:

UploadFile.xhtml -> receiveFile.java -> Thanks.xhtml (user will close this the browser) -> another program make some processing on the recently uploaded file (even if user shutsdown the PC)

I thought using a daemon program that keeps checking if a new file arrived, but I want to know if there's a way to keep executing things even if the user closes the browser.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add details about your server environment , will help to give solutions better.

Comment: JSF 2.1, Tomahawk 1.1.11 (to upload file) and Tomcat 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly the best way to do this is to have [a scheduler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) that will look for certain files every x time interval and do something with it within a thread.

Advice, make sure you shut down the scheduler on context unload. Here is an example on how to use a SchedulerService.

You would want to do something like in a [context listener](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

```
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    Runnable handler = new Runnable() {
           public void run() { 
                // handle file
           }
    };
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(handler, 10, 10, SECONDS);
```

Comment: Ok, I didn't know about the java Scheduler class thanks for that. But my question still remains. How do I let the scheduler process keep runnning even after the user closes the web-browser.     I mean I have the page where the file is uploaded and after upload finishes it redirects to a "Thank you we will process the file and then notify you". After this point I want to keep a java program running even if the user closes the browser. Thanks

Comment: The scheduler has nothing to do with the browser. If you create a new thread, the thread will execute even after the browser has closed.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try it right now and come here if I have problems. Thanks Amir Raminfar !

Comment: There is no need for a scheduler. Just create the background task in receiveFile.java and launch a new thread to run this task (or give this task to an executor service)

Comment: The scheduler runs in the Tomcat environment, so it is on the server-side. The client can open and close browsers and connections, this has no effect on what happens on the server. Tomcat continous to run, even if no browser is connected to it, correct? So you can use that to your advantage. We sometimes forget that fact when working with browser-based applications.

Comment: @JBNizet I disagree with you. Each component should do one thing in the system. To have a page that creates a new thread and uploads a file is just dirty. It is also a resource hug because each page request may create a new thread. It is much cleaner to have a daemon thread sitting in the background doing what it is intended to do. Here is a wiki on the principal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: Well I try it and my main thread hangs until the second thread finishes. The workflow is as follows     select file -> hit button to upload -> when done upload 1) create thread to process file 2) send user to thanks page. Point 1 and 2 should run concurrently and not blocking each other, but the new thread is running and until it finishes the thanks page is shown. What am I missing?

Comment: This is not what I had suggested so maybe someone else can help.

Comment: Well... maybe I didn't understand you at all, can you explain me again your idea?

Comment: @JBNizet I think what I did was what you suggested... Why is the thread blocking the main thread? My receiveFile is something like this: `..upload.. myFileVerifier mfv = new myFileVerifier(); mfv.start()` and myFileVerifier is something like this: `class myFileVerifier extends Thread{ public void run(){ //processFile } }`

Comment: @Amir : Calling a method like fileProcessor.processFileInOtherThread(file) at the end of the receiveFile method doesn't look like bad design to be. Better than constantly polling for a new file, IMHO. If the task is given to an executo service, a new thread is not created each time. A fixed thread pool or a cached thread pool may be used. This is abstracted by the executor service.

Comment: @BRabbit27 : it looks fine to me, except I would use an executor service instead of starting a new thread each time. I don't know why the thread is blocked. You'll need to ask another question with some code included.

Comment: I still dont like this model. It's less code at an expense of a model that is hard to maintain. You still have to shut down the executor. But what ever works for brabbit is what matters.

Comment: Well after all I keep Amir Raminfar's idea, seems to be working very very good. I also tried what @JBNizet said but didn't make it work that way.    Thanks to everyone who helped with this.  Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, after receiving file from client, even when client had closed their browser, file is now on the server, and you can process it free (not depend on client now) :-D

As your question, you want to launch something right after page closed. How about using annotation `@PreDestroy` or `@PostContructor` with bean scope `@ViewScoped` in JSF?

(in my mind, you can do this right after receiving file uploaded from client)

Comment: Yes, indeed. Maybe I explain myself wrong, but actually it should process the file right after the client has uploaded the file. I tried using threads but the main threads wait for the new thread to finish before returning the "final" web page...

Answer (score 0):

A reliable way to implement this would be is to have some form of meta  data saved in the database after the file upload is done.

And a separate listener like Quartz to read the meta data periodically and do the post processing.

The same metadata can contain more status flags for that meta data to avoid conflicts during file processing.

Again this would depend upon the complexity of your rrquirements.